# Pass value to new page in Flask when button is clicked

Tags: python, html, flask

Basically I have a for loop to generate N buttons. Each button has a name and an id to recognize the activity. When one of these buttons is clicked, a new HTML page is opened in order to display the info of that activity. I could open the page but I need to pass the value of the button or I won't know which activity was clicked. There must be a pattern to do this.

You can check the code here:

```
<div class="activities">
   <h2>Activities</h2>
   {% set i = [0] %}
     {% for d in data %}
       <a href ="/activity"><button class="btn btn-info" style="margin: 10px;" value="{{ indexs[i[0]] }}">{{ d }}</button></a>
       {% if i.append(i.pop() + 1) %}{% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

```
@views.route('/activity')
def activity():
   return render_template("activity.html")
```

Comment: Use Javascript to pass the buttons value when it is clicked to the backend(flask).

Comment: I tried the following but it gives me the error "; expected" ```<button value="{{ indexs[i[0]] }}" class="btn btn-info" style="margin: 10px;" onclick="window.location.href='{{ url_for( 'activity' , activity_id='value' ) }}';">{{ d }}</button>```

Answer (score 1):

*need to pass the value of the button*

Simplest way I can think of is using URL query parameters, simplified example:

HTML snippet:

```
<div>
<a href="/activity?buttonid=first"><button>first</button></a>
<a href="/activity?buttonid=second"><button>second</button></a>
<a href="/activity?buttonid=thired"><button>third</button></a>
</div>
```

Flask:

```
from flask import request
...
@views.route('/activity')
def activity():
   return "You clicked " + request.args["buttonid"] + "button"
```

*must be a pattern to do this*

FORMs (HTML tag `<form>`) are currently in use for this purpose.

Comment: I can't do that, it must be a loop.

Comment: This is simplified example, you might use your loop, for example if you wish to have text on button as buttonid, just change in your template `<a href ="/activity">` to `<a href ="/activity?buttonid={{d}}">`

Comment: ```<button value="{{ indexs[i[0]] }}" class="btn btn-info" style="margin: 10px;" onclick="window.location.href='{{ url_for( 'activity' , activity_id='value' ) }}';">{{ d }}</button>``` I tried this with no success. Then I changed the route for ```route('/activity/<int:activity_id>') def activity(activity_id)```

Comment: If you did find own solution to stated question, you might post it as answer (self-answer)

Comment: No, it does not work... I get an error "; expected" in the html